# Git keep file in repository but stop tracking local changes

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository

I have an `app.properties` file with dummy values that I have committed and pushed to my Git repository. I would now like to tell Git to:

1. Stop tracking changes to my local `app.properties` file and
2. Keep the initial `app.properties` file that was committed to my repository intact.

I have already added `*.properties` to my `.git/info/exclude` file, but `git status` is still detecting any changes that I make to my local `app.properties` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can say git that assume file  as unchanged with `--assume-unchanged` command

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged app.properties
```